# PowerPivot Formulas

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I am trying to replicate a formula from excel (which works incredibly slowly, but does work) into powerpivot to get it to run a little faster.

All the data from the PowerPivot query is brought into excel to run this:

```
=MIN(IF(Table_Query[DeliveryCard]=[@DeliveryCard],IF(Table_Query[SiteCode]=[@SiteCode],IF(Table_Query[BinGradeCode]=[@Upgrade],IF((Table_Query[WEighted Protein]+[@[WEighted Protein]])/(Table_Query[Unshrunktonnes]+[@Unshrunktonnes])>[@[Upgrade Protein]],Table_Query[SampleProteinQty])))))
```

I would essentially want to replicate this in PowerPivot which can do these calcs much faster.

Edit:

Table structure, I have approx 140K rows which have been filtered for some basic criteria to about 35K rows (are certain parameters above/below).
The structure of the two tables is identical, they are all individual entries into a database I have pulled out via PowerPivot.

The formula is looking into each entry to meach the criteria, delivery card, sitecode etc etc then returning the minimum protein to make the average of the two entries above a certain level.

Comment: how about providing a little bit of insight into your table structure and a little more description to help out those who want to help you to understand your problem better and in turn help you our sooner. Hopefully, that will make this post helpful in future to other visitors as well

Comment: Add the table to the data model and write the equivalent DAX formula there?

Comment: @QHarr - That is probably what I need to do - I just don't quite know enough about DAX to write up something that complex. Any help?

Comment: As per Bharat's comment. Insight into the table?